# Pandas dataframe getting number of categorical values that are in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to learning machine learning on datasets in `python` and am trying to perform the following on the below dataframe (only shown a snippet)

| id | country | device | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | sg | samsung | 0 |
| 100 | ch | galaxy s | 0 |
| 200 | ab | pocophone | 1 |
| 200 | ee | iphone 1 | 1 |
| 200 | my | iphone 2 | 1 |

i am trying to

1. get a list of all the countries where the labels have been = 1
2. for each id, out of all the countries , count the countries that are in the list in 1), and get the total count of the countries present for each id.

**Update:**

I have managed to get a list of countries where label = 1. For each id, how to find the number of countries that they have which falls into the list mentioned before?

Answer (score 0):

Try via loc accessor and boolean masking:

```
count=df.loc[df['label'].eq(1),['id','country']].value_counts()
#count the values of country where 'label' is 1
lst=count.index.get_level_values(1).unique().tolist()
#get the index of count for country names
```

output of `lst`:

```
['ab', 'ee', 'my']
```

output of `count`:

```
id   country
200  ab         1
     ee         1
     my         1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df.loc[ df['label'] == 1 ] ['country']
```

This will find which indices have df['label'] as 1, `loc`ate them, and take the `'country'` Series from them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

1. unique countries with label = 1

```
>>> df.query('label == 1')['country'].unique()
array(['ab', 'ee', 'my'], dtype=object)
```

2. count of unique countries per id when label = 1

```
>>> df.query('label == 1').groupby('id')['country'].nunique()
id
200    3
Name: country, dtype: int64
```

2. Updated version:

```
countries = df.query('label == 1')['country'].unique()
df.query('country in @countries').groupby('id')['country'].nunique()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. I have managed to get a list of countries where label = 1. Now what i need to do is for each id, find the number of countries that they have which falls into the list mentioned before.May I kindly ask how is that possible?

Comment: I believe this is already what my code #2 is doing. Can you give me the expected output?

Comment: with reference to my above example dataframe in the question.  `label_countries =[ 'sg', 'ch', 'ee'] . `

`id = 100` will have value of 2 while `id = 200' will have value of 1

Comment: I have managed to do it, albeit in an extremely clunky manner.  `a = calls.groupby(['id', 'country']).count().reset_index()` , `b = a[a['country'].isin(country_bot)]`, `c= b.groupby(['id']).count().reset_index()`

Comment: sir it doesnt seem to work, ends up giving the value of 1 for each id. But its okaythe clunky method i tried works